# Highlight element in navigation

Tags: css, web, html-lists

Hell I'm making a navigation where one specific Element should be highlighted from other elements of the navigation.
I created a css class highlighted where i increase font the size. But then the text is not on the same hight as the smaller texts.

```
#navigation .bar a.highlight{
font-size: large;
}
```

It looks like this:
[image]

Sorry I'm new to css and html and I guess it's an easy solution.

Please take a look at my code
http://jsfiddle.net/FcbJv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `line-height`.

Try this:

```
#navigation .bar a.highlight {
    font-size: large;
    line-height: 12px; /*Same as your font-size for normal items*/
}
```

Because your font size for the page is 12px, a `line-height` of `12px` will vertically center it. If you change the font-size, be sure to change the `line-height`.

[Check this JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/FcbJv/2/)

Answer (score 2):

First, I would suggest not using keywords like `large` in your CSS for font-size, instead use px or em units (better for maintainability, and browsers can interpret these keywords differently).

You can achieve the effect you want by decreasing the `line-height` on your `.highlight` menu item in proportion to the increase in font-size. This maintains the [vertical rythm](http://24ways.org/2006/compose-to-a-vertical-rhythm/) of your menu items.

- [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGgs4/1/)

**CSS**

```
/*EM  (personal preference) */

#navigation .bar a.highlight{
   font-size: 1.4em; /* we increase size by .4ems */
   line-height:.6em; /* so we reduce line-height by .4 ems */
}

/* PX */

#navigation .bar a.highlight{
    font-size: 18px; /* just guessing here, make sure to set this to the actual desired height */
    line-height:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aligning things vertically in CSS is one of the things that can make you go crazy.

Try improving the `line-height` of the list items:

```
line-height: 16px;
```

Also, try to be specific with the `font-size` you want instead of using `large` because it can vary from browser to browser.